# check cells for contents and enter the system time

Tags: excel, vba

I want my code to check a cell for contents.  If its blank, I want it to skip the cell and go to the next one and do the same thing.  If it is not blank, I want another cell selected and the current time entered.  The following code worked when I was checking only one cell, but when I added multiple cells (there will be 32 cells to check), I get 'Next without For'.  Then I get lost.

```
Sub time()
If Range("f2") <> "" Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("f8").Select
     ActiveCell = Format(TimeValue(Now), "h:mm a/p")
Next
If Range("h2") <> "" Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("h8").Select
     ActiveCell = Format(TimeValue(Now), "h:mm a/p")
Next
If Range("j2") <> "" Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("j8").Select
     ActiveCell = Format(TimeValue(Now), "h:mm a/p")

Else
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use `Next` when looping.  Since your cells are random, they are independent tests and each `If` needs to be closed with an `End If`

```
Sub time()

    If Range("f2") <> "" Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("f8") = Format(TimeValue(Now), "h:mm a/p")
    End If

    If Range("h2") <> "" Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("h8") = Format(TimeValue(Now), "h:mm a/p")
    End If

    If Range("j2") <> "" Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("j8") = Format(TimeValue(Now), "h:mm a/p")
    End If

End Sub
```

To do as a loop:

```
Sub time()

      Dim x as Integer

      For x= 6 to 10 Step 2
          If Cells(2,x) <> "" Then
              Cells(8,x)=Format(TimeValue(Now),"h:mm a/p")
          End If
      Next x

 End Sub
```